# Confused with python attribute getting process: infinite recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, attributes, attr, new-style-class

Suppose we want to get an object's attribute: `smth = object.attr`.
Also suppose we already know what object our attribute is located in, let it be the class called A.

As far as I know, the attribute getting procedure then looks like this:

```
attr = A.__dict__['attr']      # 1
if hasattr(attr, '__get__'):   # 2
    return attr.__get__(None, A)
else: 
    return attr
```

1. Find the descriptor in the attribute dictionary of class A.
2. Return an output of the attribute's getter if it's there. Otherwise, return the attribute itself.

I see a problem here. Suppose our attribute is a descriptor with a getter. In that case, to resolve `object.descriptor`, we have to resolve `descriptor.__get__` which, in turn, is a non-data descriptor (function) and needs to be resolved too. Where is the end of this recursion?

Comment: Resolving `attr.__get__` invokes `attr.__getattr[ibute]__`, not `attr.__get__` itself, so there's no recursive case. Or have I misunderstood the question? Which method(s) do you think lead(s) to recursion?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `attr.__get__` is an ordinary function, right? So, before using it we must: 1) find it; 2) bind it, i.e. invoke `(attr.__get__).__get__`. But the latter is an ordinary function, so...

Comment: `attr.__get__` is not itself a descriptor, though, so doesn't have a `.__get__` to find. It's not clear to me why you think this is recursive.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. Indeed, it turns out that function.__get__ is not a function but a method-wrapper (as is properpty.__get/set/delete__). And yes, method-wrapper is not a descriptor.

Comment: If you're new to descriptors, have a look at e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just had. Oddly, it has no mention of the fact that built-in 'magic' methods (`__get__`, `__set__`, `__delete__`) of built-in descriptors are not stored as functions, as opposed to normal methods. Or maybe every built-in method is a method-wrapper?